# LogisticRegression returns no results (Python)

Tags: python, regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to conduct a binomial logistic regression in python on singup conversion (0, 1) using 5-star rating (1-5). I successfully uploaded my csv to Jupyter Notebook, checked the data to confirm no nulls and datatypes are correct (int64) and everything looks right. I setup my model as:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['RATING']],df.RETENTION_FLAG,test_size=0.1)
```

and then run:

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

however the output is just LogisticRegression() with no actual results.

[image]

My notebook and the raw data can be found at: https://github.com/calebgrisell/Binomial-Regression-Python

I'm sure there's a simple explanation but I've exhausted stack overflow & youtube so any help that you can provide is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would address two things in this answer:

1. `model.fit(X_train,y_train)` returning `LogisticRegression()`:
   The model is of class `LogisticRegression()` and fitting the model doesn't change that. Hence, it would remain of class type `LogisticRegression()`
2. All classes getting classified as 0:
   This could be potentially because of the data. The dataset has all datapoints of class 1 being simultaeously classified as class 0.

This could potentially be fixed by removing the class 0 duplicates although this is not recommended.

I have changed the path to `read_csv`. Hope the solution helps! :)